# What law enforcement was there in the Neutral Zone cities

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-in-the-high-castle

In the first series of *The Man in the High Castle* we were introduced to Canon City, and the apparently small town had no visible law, given that the bounty hunter The Marshall was able to string up his kill until the birds pick the skeleton dry, yet the shops all seemed to have no visible barred windows or other defences.

Later in Denver there's at least two shooting incidents in the bar relsulting in three dead bodies, but very little commotion. If they were trying to give the image of the Wild West, why wasn't there at least a sheriff?

Comment: I think you're underestimating the influence of the hollywood cowboy movie as to the ubiquity of a town sheriff in 'the wild west'.